# how to change keybindings

Tags: modeling, shortcut

How do i switch to industry standard keybinding?
I picked default blender hotkeys after starting it up for the first time and want to try the 27x option or industry standard hotkeys.

Answer (score 1):

In the user preferences >  Keymap

[image]